# Techniques to solve a challenging integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to evaluate this integral:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left( \ln \vert x \vert \right)}{x\ln^2 \left( x \right) - x} dx$$

However, I am not exactly sure where to start. You seem to be able to sub $u = \ln x$, but this doesn't seem to make much of a difference. I know the answer is  $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$. 
Help appreciated!

Comment: You have a problem with the integrand.  If $x \in (0,1)$, then $\log |x| \in (-\infty, 0)$, and $\log(\log |x|)$ is not real-valued when $\log |x| < 0$.

Comment: To add to the above comment, you probably want $\ln|\ln(x)|$ rather than $\ln(\ln|x|)$...

Comment: Taking the above comments into account, you can let $y=-\ln x$, so the integral becomes the fairly well-known,$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln y}{y^2-1}\,dy$$

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you, I was able to find a solution for this problem.